# robocopy advantages and disadvantages

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, backup, robocopy

Could you, please, list what do you think that are main advantages and main disadvantages of robocopy?

Thanks.

Comment: How could any of us here possibly justify **your** arbitrary software choice. Robocopy is *bad* as a standalone backup solution. I'd never consider it. If you want to use it, you'll need to justify it - not us.

Comment: @MDMarra, happy now :)

Comment: @zoredache, why is this closed? I have edited the question and reformulated it. I don't see which rules does it break now?`Thanks

Comment: Please read our [faq] and [ask]. If you have a specific question about how the site works, you should ask on [meta]. This is a very open-ended question and doesn't fit the standards for this site. Seriously, read the [faq] and if you need further clarification, ask on [meta]. Also Zordache is only 1 of 5 users that voted to close this. He didn't act unilaterally. You can also ask for clarification in [chat] if you'd like.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a comprehensive list but I'll give it a crack

Advantages:

- Free / no renewal cost
- Easy and quick file-based backup
- Scriptable on any machine to any network based resource
- Has both a command line and [GUI](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx) for learning the options
- Can log output

Disadvantages:

- No image based recovery
- Backup Speed based on network traffic and architecture (although, this is true of every backup program)
- No tech support if something goes wrong

FYI: Be aware of [how robocopy handles symbolic links](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/windows-7-infinite-loop-while-using-robocopy/20f32f0c-4cb9-4125-923d-6a57e4d27232) in newer versions of windows